# Remove commas after my values

Tags: php

My query is SELECT 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  eemail_email_sub FROM  wp_eemail_newsletter_sub GROUP BY  eemail_email_sub  ");
 my ouput result is 
    ArbutusHill.BarbraSundquist.dalybakker@gmail.com
    BradSelers.UniqueArticle.noel56@fatmarketing.com
    comments@prologicwebsolutions.com
    GavinBurnham.GavinBurnham.graham.beevis@virgin.net
    KatieSmith.KatieSmith.rebepa333@yahoo.com
    TerryStanfield.JuanitaMoreno.seo@clickadvant.com

```
I want show my result is

ArbutusHill.BarbraSundquist.dalybakker@gmail.com
BradSelers.UniqueArticle.noel56@fatmarketing.com
after again run query is my reslut show next two email
like this
```

TerryStanfield.LeslieGonzales.seo@clickadvant.com
    TerryStanfield.MarionMorales.seo@clickadvant.com

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` function in your select query

Comment: If you want to remove the last comma, push them all to an array, and use `implode` (the reverse of `explode`).

Comment: What's the issue with your code ? I suggest you provide the output and point out what's wrong and why, and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

not 100% on the logic of your code and if all the relevant lines are there but once you have your variable just trim it.

```
$variable = 'Assembled Computer Repair & Services,CCTV Cameras,';
$variable = rtrim($variable, ',');
```

Or you could use substring aswell.

```
$variable = substr($variable, 0, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As martincarlin87 stated, you can use rtrim or substring.

Be aware that rtrim removes all commas at the end of the string, so 'foobar,,' would become 'foobar' instead of 'foobar,'.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
$var = "Assembled Computer Repair & Services,CCTV Cameras,";
   $variable = substr(trim($var) , 0, -1);
```